# Can't make a copy of the object by dereferencing unique_ptr but have a segfault

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

Really have been tortured a lot by the `unique_ptr` thing.

So, I've defined a `private` member function of class `C` which is like:

```
std::vector<T1> C::mem_fun(std::unique_ptr<T2>& a1,
                           std::vector<T1>& a2,
                           std::vector<T3>& a3) {
    std::vector<T1> b1;
    for (struct {std::vector<T1>::iterator it;
                 std::vector<T3>::iterator iu;}
            gi = {a2.begin(), a3.begin()};
            gi.it != a2.end(); ++gi.it, ++gi.iu) {
        T1 b2;
        ...
        if (...)
            b2.ptr = std::move(gi.it->ptr);
        else {
            ...
            std::unique_ptr<T4> ptr(new T4()); // line 1
            *ptr = *(gi.it->ptr); // line 2 -----> which causes a segfault!!!!
            b2.ptr = std::move(ptr); // line 3
        }
        ...
        b1.push_back(std::move(b2));
    }
    return b1;
}
```

where `T1` is like:

```
typedef struct T1 {
    int t1_a;
    double t1_b;
    std::unique_ptr<T4> ptr;
} T1;
```

Why would that statement cause a segfault? Anything wrong with `*(gi.it->ptr)`? Or what else? I've heard from somewhere that `get()` might help, but it turns out not...

What I want to do for line 1-3 basically is make a copy of the object pointed by `gi.it->ptr` and let the `ptr` member of `b2` point to that copy. Not sure if there are any good solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you modifying the vector `a2` or `a3` at all?  Modifying the vector will more than likely invalidate the iterators that you have causing a segfualt.

Comment: I think I kinda know why there is a segfault, although I'm not so sure. Actually this function is called multiple times and each time `a2` might be modified by `b2.ptr = std::move(gi.it->ptr);`, which nullifies the original `ptr` pointed by `gi.it`. The next time when `*ptr = *(gi.it->ptr);` is executed, `gi.it->ptr` is already `nullptr`, I guess. Dereferencing a `nullptr` would cause a segfault (?)

Comment: Questions asking "why does this segfault" should include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Does T4 have a valid copy constructor for your use case? If so:

`b2.ptr = new unique_ptr<T4>(new T4(*gi.it->ptr.get()));`

Will do what you want.

Comment: Why do you say you can't set `*ptr`?  `unique_ptr` doesn't prevent such a thing.

Comment: "You can't set `*ptr`." - um. yes you can. `operator *` is overloaded for `std::unique_ptr` to return a reference to the pointed-to object. In the OP's code the *prior line* creates the object. If anything, `*ptr = ...` is firing an *assignment* operator for `T4` (which is probably where the wheels are falling off).

Comment: I think I know why there is a segfault. This function would be called multiple times and each time `a2` might be modified by `b2.ptr = std::move(gi.it->ptr);`, which makes the original `ptr` pointed by `gi.it` equal to `nullptr`. The next time when `*ptr = *(gi.it->ptr);` is executed, `gi.it->ptr` is already `nullptr`. Dereferencing a `nullptr` would cause a segfault (?) But anyway, I will take @dan-O 's method for reference. Regardless of my original problem, wouldn't it be just OK to use `=` to simply copy values of a struct to another, since the compiler would just provide a copy function?

Comment: @aschepler and WhozCraig , you are correct. Not sure why I made that claim. I have edited my response accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @dan-O, shouldn't it be `new T4(*gi.it->ptr)` since you don't want to construct a `T4` from a `T4*`. I would just do `b2.ptr.reset(new T4(*gi.it->ptr))`

Comment: @WanxinGao, yes, dereferencing nullptr will segfault.